# Router hangs once in a while

Tags: networking, router, internet

What are the issues that cause a router to hang? I have a router that has 15 machines of which 3 are on WiFi. Also there are 2 ip cameras. The network is entirely dedicated for a project relating to the camera, so the camera is accessed and video is streamed through that continuously. So my router doesn't respond once in a while. but a restart solves the issue. My router is a Cisco linksys E1200. Any help or suggestions on this ?

Comment: Could be running out of connections.  When you say "hang", what do you mean exactly?  Are you able to ping it or access the web config?

Comment: @Paul i meant that the router becomes irresponsive. I cant ping the router. And the people connected to that doesn't have a internet access. I keep doing a power off and on.

Comment: @Paul What are the number of connections that such routers can have ?

Comment: The first step would be to upgrade the router firmware.  Unless you have a loop somewhere in the network - do you have any other network hardware in this scenario?

Comment: @Paul I have an unconfigurable 24-port switch in this. Is that a problem ? other than that no hardware and no loop. But the camera do keep generating UDP packets. Is that a problem ?

Comment: Just sending packets won't be the issue - by "connections" I mean many concurrent but individual TCP or UDP sessions.  Sometimes this can saturate the connection table of smaller routers.  The fact that it is not responsive to pings suggests it has crashed, so a firmware upgrade is the first step.

Comment: @Paul thanks for the suggestion paul. Will try to do that ! and can you suggest me some good routers for a office based set up? may be something that can handle some 30-40 machines? if its a wifi router, then well n good.